# RMagick + Rails + Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rmagick

I'm trying to figure out how to get rmagick on my app, and then make it work on Heroku?

Comment: What have you done so far, and what's not working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok so for future reference heres what needs to be done.

In your .gems file you need:

```
rmagick
```

and then in your config/environment.rb file you need:

```
config.gem "rmagick",
:lib => "RMagick"
```

Because its already preinstalled with heroku - this does the trick.

Comment: Hello, I have added the previous lines in config/environnement.rb but it does not work when I run rails s.

Comment: Luc, it's because the point is that Heroku's servers already have rmagick installed. (This is because it's a pain to install correctly, of course.) Running 'rails s' uses your own local gems, which do require you to have setup imagemagick and rmagick yourself.

Answer (score 21):

For Rails3, you have to add this specification:

gem "rmagick", "2.12.0", :require => 'RMagick'

Note: require is CAsE SeNSITIvE

Comment: Upvote for creative way to quickly get across what case sensitive means.

Answer (score 7):

Once I did the following from capps answer.

```
gem "rmagick", "2.12.0", :require => 'RMagick'
```

Then I added the require statement to any file uses rmagick it fixed my issue.

```
require 'RMagick'
```

This worked on Heroku cedar stack running rails 3.1

Answer (score 4):

It depends on which stack you are using on Heroku.  The default Aspen stack includes a lot of gems preloaded.  For compatibility reasons, the newer Bamboo stack has no preinstalled gems.  It is always better to define your gem dependencies in the .gems manifest or in the new bundler style Gemfile.

More info:
Stacks: http://docs.heroku.com/stack
Gems:  http://docs.heroku.com/gems

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to add a require statement in whatever class. It's case sensitive!

```
mike@sleepycat:~/projects/myapp$ heroku console --app myapp
Ruby console for myapp.heroku.com
>> require 'RMagick'
=> []
>> include Magick
=> Object
```

I don't have that in my .gems file or anything, and there it is in my console, so it seems that it is just there by default.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is quite old but I just ran into this myself.

`gem 'rmagick', '2.16.0', :require => 'rmagick'`

Worked for me. According to my Heroku logs `RMagick` is deprecated in favor of `rmagick` (all lower case).

Hope this helps the future Googler.

Comment: what version of heroku stack was this for?

Comment: I want to say it was Heroku-16 and I was running Rails 5.0.2 on Ruby 2.3.5 at the time, iirc.